# Using Wi-Fi P2P to create Write Service

Tags: android, wifip2p

I am trying to communicate Android devices.
Does Android Wifi P2P have ability to create Service not just to read characteristics but and/or to write?
I would like to have something looks like GATT in BLE.

Comment: Are you talking about wifiDirect? Not sure what was the meaning when they created that, avoid having to create a wifi network and connect to it? to do what you want you only need to use a ServerSocket right?

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use device to create a wifi hotspot and connect other devices

2.you can use wifidirect, please refer this: https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/index.html

Comment: I have created Service successfully like in 
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd-wifi-direct.html
But what about Creating Service that will not only populate information but Service that will listen for write into characteristic (Like iBeacon)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to android devices through wifi direct and start the communication.

Check this for more information:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Once connection is done, you can use socket to transfer files.

Here is my github project about wifi direct transfer:
https://github.com/Youxian-Chen/WiFiDirectTransfer

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you. I don't need to connect devices, just Discover Nearby Services and read Record data. But I want also write some data to found Service.

Comment: maybe you can try doing the same thing in found Service, so it can get the Record data you want to write to it.

Comment: and if you just want to communicate to android devices. you can also try NFC. here is the link for more information http://blog.opendatalab.de/hack/2013/11/25/android-p2p-nfc/ and i also use nfc communication to share wifi hotspot https://github.com/Youxian-Chen/WiFiShare

Comment: ok, i think you can try i mentioned above. addLocalService and Record data in both devices. so when it detect each other. they can exchange data.

Comment: No I use this logic, but discovering devices on WifiDirect  isn't good. i mean it doesn't find every time each other.